# How to get Credentials for Ning API using OAuth?

Tags: android, api

Can anyone help me in obtaining OAuth credentials for NING API ?
I need to integrate Ning With my Android app how can i do so ?

Any Idea or example or any help is acceptable....
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the network owner to generate an application key + secret for you. The API key management page is found via the "API Keys" link of the Tools section of the management page. Note that the API is only available for networks using Ning Pro.

See: http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/overview/authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

> I need to integrate Ning With my Android app how can i do so ?

You have to do this yourself, no one will write the code for you. 
Here is the link to the [api documentation](http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/_downloads/NingApi.pdf)

There are samples in [python](http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/examples/python/python.html), PHP and curl which you can use as a reference, if you understand the language.

Here's how to use [restful API's](http://timewasted.net/?p=127) and a tutorial for [Oauth on Android](http://nilvec.com/implementing-client-side-oauth-on-android/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i know REST Web Parsing, that is later part bt i dont know from where can i get the credentials using OAUTH for the same...do i need to integrate Ning with either twitter or FB in order to get keys and callback urls ???

Comment: Read this article on [Authentication with Ning](http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/overview/authentication.html)